# js, find / match/ search if element stored data by data name

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, match

I want to find out whether if a element has stored specific data.

For example, if a element has a data and the name called `DATA + etc`.

```
$el.data('DATA' + 'etc', value);
```

If I only know the name will be DATA + something but I dont know what is the something.

How can i `find out / search / match` if the element has data and its name started with `'DATA'`.

```
alert($el.data('DATA') ? 'Yes' : 'No')
```

Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: you can use selectors?http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: @user711819 only for `data-*` attributes. While jQuery does automagically turn those into values that `.data()` can access, that's not going to work for other such `.data()`'d values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.data()` with no arguments](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) gets you an object of the attached data, so you can iterate over the keys to see if any of them start with `'DATA'`.

```
var hasMatchingData = false;
var allData = $el.data();
for (var key in allData) {
    if (allData.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.match(/^DATA/g)) {
        hasMatchingData = true;
        break;
    }
}
alert(hasMatchingData ? 'Yes' : 'No')
```

Answer (score 0):

Store a object for the 'DATA' key. Then add your etc property onto that object.

A check can be done by writing

```
'propertyName' in object
```

Comment: the name is 'propertyName' + etc, I want to know how can i match is I dont know the etc